# Sliding window algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, networking, computer-science

I am having trouble figuring how to derive the numbers to the solution to the question. I am following the steps, however my numbers do not come near that of the solution. Can someone give a concise step by step way to figuring out both problems. [image]

Solution

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for `cs.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part a

`T = 0 RTT` Sender sends frames 0, 1 and 2 (theoretically) simultaneously.

`T = 0.5RTT` Receiver receives frames 0,1 and 2. Receiver updates `LFR = 2`, `LAF = 5`. Receiver sends `ACK` for each of the three frames.

`T = 1 RTT` Sender receives ACK for frames 0, 1, and 2, and sends out frames 3,4, and 5. Sender updates `LAR = 2`, and `LFS = 5`.

`T = 1.5 RTT` Receiver receives frames 3 and 5. Receiver updates `LFR = 3`, `LAF = 6`. It sends an `ACK` for frame 3.

`T = 2 RTT` Sender receives ACK for frame 3, and sends out frame 6. Sender updates `LAR = 3`, and `LFS = 6`.

`T = 2.7 RTT` Sender times out on frame `4`.

#### Part b

`T = 0 RTT` Sender sends frames 0, 1 and 2 (theoretically) simultaneously.

`T = 0.5RTT` Receiver receives frames 0,1 and 2. Receiver updates `LFR = 2`, `LAF = 5`. Receiver sends `ACK` for each of the three frames.

`T = 1 RTT` Sender receives ACK for frames 0, 1, and 2, and sends out frames 3,4, and 5. Sender updates `LAR = 2`, and `LFS = 5`.

`T = 1.5 RTT` Receiver receives frames 3,4, and 5. Receiver updates `LFR = 5`, `LAF = 8`. It sends an ACK for each of the frames received.

`T = 2 RTT` Sender receives ACK for frame 5, and sends out frames 6,7, 8. Sender updates `LAR = 5`, and `LFS = 8`.

`T = 2.5 RTT` Receiver receives frames 6,7, and 8. Receiver updates `LFR = 8`, `LAF = 11`. It sends an ACK for each of the frames received.

`T = 2.7 RTT` Sender is times out on frame `4`.

Comment: How did you attain 2.7 RTT? and how did you conclude to increment the T by .5?

Comment: @jssmkp, `2.7 RTT = 1 RTT + TIMEOUT (1.7 RTT)`, and I am making the assumption that sending packets one way requires `0.5 RTT`.

Comment: Lastly, on the solution for part B, it gets LAR = 5/6, LFS = 8/9, you conclude differently. Do you know how one would get these fractions?